# Issues with writing output to file in C++

Tags: c++

I am writing to a file in C++ in append mode, the program which I am using for the same is:

```
#include <fstream>
void main()
{
 ofstream f;
 f.open("f.txt", ios::app);
 f<<"\n Hello";
 f.close();
}
```

Now the output which is getting printed in the output file is some thing junk...which I can't comprehend:

```
  OUTPUT:
  牐湩㩴
```

Please help me as to where am i going wrong???
I am working on linux.

Comment: It's because you need to convert the text you are outputting to UTF-8 first.

Comment: http://www2.research.att.com/~bs/bs_faq2.html#void-main

Comment: Interestingly enough, if you translate that from Chinese to English in Google Translate it says something about breast-feeding.

Comment: `void main()` is not C++. Please make it `int main()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The file which you are appending to has a BOM marker indicating it is UTF-16 encoded. Recreate the file using an editor which will not encode the file, or use a program to write it from scratch.

Answer (score 1):

This is because you didn't specify a text encoding, and in the absence of explicit encoding markings, Windows just guesses. The most famous instance of this is [Bush Hid The Facts](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bush_hid_the_facts)